# How does vim receive f1-f4?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings

Literal terminal code of `<f4>` is:

```
^[OS
```

result of `set <f4>` is:

```
t_k4 <F4>        ^[[14;*~
```

They are totally different, unlike results of f5-f12 (which are the same except the modifier related sequence).

Both of following command will trigger `<f4>`

```
call feedkeys('^[OS')
call feedkeys('^[[14~')
```

I also need to add extra setting to make `<c-f[1-4]>` and `<s-f[1-4]>` work properly:

```
...
set <f16>=^[[1;2S
map <f16> <s-f4>

set <f28>=^[[1;5S
map <f28> <c-f4>
```

Why are f1-f4 special, what's the relationship between their terminal code and vim's t_xx key codes ?

I'm using vim8.1-1432 on ubuntu16.04.

Comment: For what it's worth, pressing F4 in vi in my git-bash issues `^[OS`, while pressing F4 in vi in my CentOS terminal accessed via Putty issues `^[[14~`. So vi probably accepts both as synonyms if different terminals feed vi different strings to express the same key, which would explain the identical behaviour of the two `feedkeys` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:h xterm-function-keys`

```
An xterm can send function keys F1 to F4 in two modes: vt100 compatible or
not.  Because Vim may not know what the xterm is sending, both types of keys
are recognized.  The same happens for the <Home> and <End> keys.
            normal                      vt100 ~
    <F1>    t_k1    <Esc>[11~   <xF1>   <Esc>OP     *<xF1>-xterm*
    <F2>    t_k2    <Esc>[12~   <xF2>   <Esc>OQ     *<xF2>-xterm*
    <F3>    t_k3    <Esc>[13~   <xF3>   <Esc>OR     *<xF3>-xterm*
    <F4>    t_k4    <Esc>[14~   <xF4>   <Esc>OS     *<xF4>-xterm*
    <Home>  t_kh    <Esc>[7~    <xHome> <Esc>OH     *<xHome>-xterm*
    <End>   t_@7    <Esc>[4~    <xEnd>  <Esc>OF     *<xEnd>-xterm*

When Vim starts, <xF1> is mapped to <F1>, <xF2> to <F2> etc.  This means that
by default both codes do the same thing.  If you make a mapping for <xF2>,
because your terminal does have two keys, the default mapping is overwritten,
thus you can use the <F2> and <xF2> keys for something different.
```